# Monomorphisms and epimorphisms in the functors

Tags: category-theory

Do functors preserve monomorphisms and epimorphisms?
The functors reflect monomorphisms and epimorphisms?

The functor that goes from category $2$ that has two objects and three arrows to the $\mathbb{Z}$-Mod category does not preserve monomorphisms or epimorphisms.

Are there any other examples that do not preserve monomorphisms and epimorphisms?

Is there an example that does not reflect monomorphisms and epimorphisms?

Comment: In the category of Hausdorff spaces the map that embeds $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ is an epimorphism that is not preserved by the forgetful functor.

Comment: The trivial functor that goes to the one-point one-arrow category is a functor which struggles very hard to reflect anything.

Comment: The unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings, but this epimorphicity (epimorphismness?) is not preserved by the forgetful functor to the category of sets.